# Define Haskell type with multiple contained types

Tags: haskell, types

My goal is to replace a signature like

```
execute :: [Instruction] -> State -> Pointer -> State
```

with

```
execute :: Program -> State
```

I created the type synonym

```
type Program = [Instruction] -> State -> Pointer
```

When I define the implementation (e.g. `execute [] s _ = s`), I receive the following compile error:

```
Couldn't match expected type ‘State -> Pointer -> State’
            with actual type ‘[Int]’
The equation(s) for ‘execute’ have three arguments,
but its type ‘Program -> State’ has only one
```

Without replacing `[Instruction] -> State -> Pointer` with `Program`, it compiles. It appears to attempt to match the `Program` type to only the first argument. Is there a way to  match the `Program` type over the first three arguments?

Comment: `execute :: [Instruction] -> State -> Pointer -> State` is equivalent to `execute :: [Instruction] -> (State -> Pointer -> State)` and not to `execute :: ([Instruction] -> State -> Pointer) -> State`, if I recall correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your type synonym is actually a function type (of 2 arguments, uncurried). So when you have a function

```
fun :: Programm -> State
fun p = ...
```

that `p` is a function that needs 2 arguments, namely one `[Instruction]` and one `State` to produce a `Pointer`. But you only get the function, not the needed instructions nor the state. (And no pointer, only if this can be computed from the instructions and the state, but then why have it as parameter to the original function...)

What you seem to want is packing three arguments into one. A tuple is good therefore:

```
type Program = ([Instruction], State, Pointer)
```

Or use record syntax:

```
data Program = Program {
  instructionsOf :: [Instruction],
  stateOf :: State,
  pointerOf :: Pointer }
```

Then your code comes closer to English:

```
fun :: Program -> State
fun program = run (instructionsOf program)  -- or whatever
```

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. I was originally looking for a way to shorten the signature without changing the implementation, but using a tuple/record will certainly shorten it while making the implementation better.